# Getting random Tumblr blogs/posts

Tags: web-scraping, tumblr, pytumblr

I'm working on a data mining project for a class, and part of our project involves obtaining a large set of random posts from Tumblr.  Unfortunately, it seems that the Tumblr API (specifically using PyTumblr) has no direct capacity to do this, since it requires either a specific blog name or tag.  Is there any reasonable way to do this?  My best idea is to grab blog names and/or tags from posts on Trending, but I'm not sure that will be adequate for our purposes.  We ultimately want a data set that can be partitioned into posts that are tagged with one or more tags from a specified set, and posts that contain none of those tags.

Comment: What blogs, I am not sure that Tumblr provides an easy interface, but for random posts from a blog you can navigate to *{BlogURL}/random*

Comment: @AdamAzad Random posts from random blogs.  I have no foreknowledge about blog names because that would defeat the purpose of a random sample.  Also, I'm beginning to wonder if Tumblr provides an easy anything.

Comment: Have you been to [Explore Up and Coming](https://www.tumblr.com/explore/up-and-coming)? You can crawl it.

Comment: @AdamAzad, but it shows personalized recommendations. Just something to have in mind.

Comment: @AdamAzad That just redirects to Trending.